# ClassNotFoundException With external libraries in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using some external/custom libraries in spring boot(1.5.13.RELEASE) maven application. I uploaded custom jars to our local artifactory server and added them as dependencies in pom.xml. When i run the Spring boot Application main class from Eclipse(Oxygen), everything is running fine. When i packaged the application and run it outside of eclipse (like commandline) using java -jar "jar filename", I am getting  ClassNotFoundException. i verified the packaged jar file and i could see the custom jar i am using inside \BOOT-INF\lib directory but still getting ClassNotFoundException. I am using few other custom jars but only having issue with one particular jar. Can somebody help me resolving this issue?.

Exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve class com.ciq.pubsub.tr
    ansport.esb.EsbTransport in assembly CapitalIQ.PubSub.Transport.ESB.jar: com.ciq
    .pubsub.transport.esb.EsbTransport
            at com.ciq.pubsub.transport.TransportFactory.createTransport(TransportFa
    ctory.java:71) ~[CapitalIQPubSubTransport-4.1.jar!/:na]
            at com.spgmi.pipeline.implV2.HermesObjSetProvider.<init>(HermesObjSetPro
    vider.java:56) ~[SPGMIPipeline-4.4.jar!/:4.4]
            at com.spgmi.pipeline.implV2.DeliveryContextManager.get(DeliveryContextM
    anager.java:92) ~[SPGMIPipeline-4.4.jar!/:4.4]
            at com.spgmi.pipeline.implV2.DeliveryContextManager.ResolveContext(Deliv
    eryContextManager.java:74) ~[SPGMIPipeline-4.4.jar!/:4.4]
            at com.spgmi.pipeline.implV2.ContentPipeline.getDeliveryContext(ContentP
    ipeline.java:260) ~[SPGMIPipeline-4.4.jar!/:4.4]
            ... 58 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ciq.pubsub.transport.esb.EsbTra
    nsport
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
            at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_1
    21]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
            at com.ciq.pubsub.transport.TransportFactory.createTransport(TransportFa
    ctory.java:67) ~[CapitalIQPubSubTransport-4.1.jar!/:na]
            ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Below is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gcc-news-publishing-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcc-news-publishing-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gcc-news-publishing-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Interfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubInterfaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.Config.Dynamic</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfigDynamic</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.Config.Factory</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfigFactory</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.Config.Interfaces</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfigInterfaces</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.Config.Internal</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfigInternal</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.Config</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfig</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Java.ConfigServiceStub</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubJavaConfigServiceStub</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Transport.ESB</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubTransportESB</artifactId>
                            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Transport.Informatica</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubTransportInformatica</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>CapitalIQ.PubSub.Transport</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CapitalIQPubSubTransport</artifactId>
                            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>SPGMIPipelineInterfaces</groupId>
                            <artifactId>SPGMIPipelineInterfaces</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>cSPGMIPipelineConfiguration</groupId>
                            <artifactId>SPGMIPipelineConfiguration</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>SPGMIPipelineObjectSets</groupId>
                            <artifactId>SPGMIPipelineObjectSets</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>SPGMIPipeline</groupId>
                            <artifactId>SPGMIPipeline</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>persistence-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.osgi.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>

</dependency>
<!--  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

</dependency>
-->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b32</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>sonic_Client</groupId>
 <artifactId>sonic_Client</artifactId>
 <version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>sonic_Client_ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sonic_Client_ext</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>sonic_Crypto</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sonic_Crypto</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>sonic_mgmt_client</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sonic_mgmt_client</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>UMS_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</groupId>
                            <artifactId>UMS_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.0_12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>UMSPDM_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</groupId>
                            <artifactId>UMSPDM_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.0_12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>UMSSDM_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</groupId>
                            <artifactId>UMSSDM_6.8_jdk1.5.0_12</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.0_12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>registry</groupId>
                            <artifactId>registry</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>openmdx-kernel</groupId>
                            <artifactId>openmdx-kernel</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b32</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <name>S and P artifactory server</name>
            <url>http://nj09mhf5479.mhf.mhc:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>artifactory-snapshot</id>
            <name>S and P artifactory server</name>
            <url>http://nj09mhf5479.mhf.mhc:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>



    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://nj09mhf5479.mhf.mhc:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>

        <repository>
            <name>central</name>
            <url>http://nj09mhf5479.mhf.mhc:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <id>central</id>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>central-snap</id>
            <name>central-snap</name>
            <url>http://nj09mhf5479.mhf.mhc:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
        </snapshotRepository>

    </distributionManagement> 


</project>
```

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml in question. And Is all the custom jar file is placed in same location ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. i have placed all the jars in the same location. I am not able to paste entire pom.xml as it is complaining too long. is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: Are you adding  pom.xml in comment ? Please update in Question

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. i just added pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mvn install:install-file`.
Here's a example from: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion but didn't work. i am still getting the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with "maven-install-plugin"?
http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. i have tried other 2 options and still it didn't work.